# period between and compare am and pm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

the problem is the system should be check the period is not exists he can do this when the start time and end time be in pm together or am

but if the stert time in pm and the end time in am he dosen work like jhon booking from_hour = 22pm to_hour = 2am and lion booking from_hour = 23pm to_hour = 1am The system allows this to happen

But there must be an error here, a timing conflict, and the period must have been set before

this code is run when the From_hour and to_hour be in pm together or am

note(this website booking stadiums by horse)

how can be run if the from_hour = pm and to_hour = am

my models is :

```
class OpeningHours(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
pitche = models.ForeignKey(Pitche,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
made_on = models.DateField()
from_hour = models.TimeField()
to_hour = models.TimeField()
timing = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=timing)

def clean(self):
    if self.from_hour == self.to_hour:
        raise ValidationError('Wrong Time')
    if self.made_on < datetime.date.today():
        raise ValidationError('InVaild Date')
                
    if (
        OpeningHours.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk)
        .filter(
            made_on=self.made_on,
            pitche_id=self.pitche_id,
            to_hour__gt=self.from_hour,
            from_hour__lt=self.to_hour,
        )
        .exists()
    ):
        raise ValidationError(
            f'The booked time ({self.from_hour} to {self.to_hour}) is occupied.'
        )
    return super().clean()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation.